# how to add two directives to one field

Tags: angular

I have two directives `toPercentage` where multiply number with 100, and the other one `isRounding` where choose the digits after .00(decimal), both are working one by one but together not !

```
<input type="number" name="name" toPercentage isRounding [ngModel]="val.employerShare" (ngModelChange)="val.employerShare = $event">
```

These two directives implement a custom value accessor and It throws this error when I use them both in an input field

> Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute at _throwError

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, forwardRef, EventEmitter, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgModel } from "@angular/forms";


@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][toPercentage]',
    providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => ToPercentDirective),
    multi: true
}],
host: {
    "[value]": 'ngModel',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
}
})

export class ToPercentDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) { }

private innerValue: string;
private toNumber: number;
private toPercent:number;

public onChangeCallback : any = (_) => { console.log(_) }
public onTouched: any = () => { /*Empty*/ }


onBlur(){
    var input = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    this.toPercent  = parseFloat(input) / 100;

    if(input != this.toNumber){
    this.onChangeCallback(this.toPercent);
    }
}

writeValue(val: string): void {
    // this.ngModel.ControlValueAccessor.writeValue(val);
    this.toNumber = parseFloat(val) * 100;
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.toNumber;
}

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    // console.log(fn);
    this.onChangeCallback  = fn;
}

registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    // console.log(fn);
    this.onTouched = fn;
}

setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) : void{
    this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
}
```

}

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR  } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
selector: '[isRounding]',
providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => IsRoundingDirective),
    multi: true
}],
host: {
    "[value]": 'ngModel',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
}
})
export class IsRoundingDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(el.nativeElement.getAttribute('isRounding'));
    this.numberPad = el.nativeElement.getAttribute('isRounding') || 2;
}

private numberPad = 2;
isRoundingFlag = localStorage.getItem('isRounding');

public onChangeCallback : any = (_) => { console.log(_) }

onBlur() {
    var input = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    input = this.roundNumber(input) || null;

    this.onChangeCallback(input);
    this.el.nativeElement.value = input;
}

writeValue(val: string): void {
    if(this.isRoundingFlag === 'true') {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.roundNumber(val);
    }else {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = val;
    }
}

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback  = fn;
}

registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
}

roundNumber(val) {
    var roundedValue = parseFloat(val);
    return roundedValue.toFixed(this.numberPad) || '';
}
```

}

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: This needs your code and specific error/fail to diagnose. There is nothing new about multiple directives in use as it happens all the time with the ones right out of the box. Your code is the issue here, so you need to show it.

Comment: if i remove one of them ( toPercentage, or  isRounding ) than is ok , but together i cant use like it is..

Comment: "is ok - otherwise "not ok" is no usable information. What exactly is happening differently from what you expect when you have both applied?

Comment: Which is why you need to edit your question to show what each directive is expected to be doing. Again, the problem is your code in the directives and not an "Angular problem" with "multiple directives"

Comment: Post the code of the directives.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated again the question sorry for not providing more information from the beggining

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit older question, but I had a similar problem attempting to attach a 'masking' directive to a Custom Form Control which used the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and this was the only stackOverflow question I found that matched my issue; so I'm mentioning my resolution if anyone else hits this too.

After a lot of searching I found we could use NgControl to access the form control object, then subscribe to the valueChanges to be notified when the value changed. In this case I suppose you could make your rounding or percentage changes and use patchValue({value}) to update it with the new change (of course you will need to watch out that your change doesn't create an eternal loop)

```
import {
    Directive
    , OnChanges
    , Optional
    , Input
    , SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMyDirective]',
    providers: []
})
export class MyDirective implements OnChanges {

    @Input()
    value: any;

    constructor(@Optional() private ngControl: NgControl) {
        if (this.ngControl) {
            this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
                // do something with the value change here. 
            });
        }
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.value) {
            // do something with the value here
        }
    }

}
```

Note: I included ngOnChanges in case you are attaching the directive to a non-form object.